# Magento - Admin URL Shows Front End 404 (Csutom Module)

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.9

I am creating a Magento module to allow products to be reported.
I have done the front end okay and all is working there.

I have come to create an admin area for the module and am having a lot of trouble.
When I click on the menu item for my module (Catalog > Reported Products), it renders the front end of the website. (The url is as expected though "domain.com/index.php/admin/reported_products/adminhtml/key/76f4724a69.../"). This displays a 404 page.

I've tried a lot of variations on the action of the menu item but nothing has worked.
I've also changed the `front_name` under the `admin` node, but nothing :/

I'll try to present the files in a nice order...

**app/code/local/Tbe/Report/etc/config.xml**

```
<modules>
    <Tbe_Report>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Tbe_Report>
</modules>

<global>

    <helpers>
        <report>
            <class>Tbe_Report_Helper</class>
        </report>
    </helpers>

    <blocks>
        <report>
            <class>Tbe_Report_Block</class>
        </report>
    </blocks>


    <models>

        <report>
            <class>Tbe_Report_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>report_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </report>

        <report_mysql4>
            <class>Tbe_Report_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <report>
                    <table>report</table>
                </report>
            </entities>
        </report_mysql4>

    </models>


    <resources>

        <report_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Tbe_Report</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </report_setup>

        <report_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </report_write>

        <report_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </report_read>

    </resources>

</global>


<frontend>

    <routers>
        <report>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Tbe_Report</module>
                <frontName>report</frontName>
            </args>
        </report>
    </routers>

    <layout>
        <updates>
            <report>
                <file>report.xml</file>
            </report>
        </updates>
    </layout>  

</frontend>



<adminhtml>

    <routers>
        <report>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Tbe_Report</module>
                <frontName>reported_products</frontName>
            </args>
        </report>
    </routers>

   <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Tbe_Report after="Mage_Adminhtml">Tbe_Report</Tbe_Report>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

</adminhtml>
```

**app/code/local/Tbe/Report/etc/adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <menu>
            <catalog translate="title" module="report">
                <title>Catalog</title>
                <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <report>
                        <title>Reported Products</title>
                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/reported_products/reported/</action>
                    </report>
                </children>
            </catalog>
        </menu>

        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>                
                        <tbe translate="title" module="report">
                            <title>View Reported Products</title>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        </tbe>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>

    </config>
```

**app/code/core/local/Tbe/Report/controllers/ReportedController.php**

```
class Tbe_Report_ReportedController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();

    }

}
```

Yes, I do have a blank Data.php under Tbe/Report/Helpers/

Any and all help is appreciated.

## **UPDATE**

I have managed to get it working (somewhat).
The only issue now is the `<action>` node in adminhtml.xml.

If I DO NOT prepend the action with `adminhtml`, the page renders, showing the admin header and footer (I haven't done any content yet). However, the URL does not contain /admin. Instead, the URL is "http://domain.com/index.php/reported_products/reported/key/88bf4.../".

If I do prepend the action with `adminhtml`, It renders the front end header and footer but goes to the correct url "http://domain.com/index.php/admin/reported_products/reported/key/88bf4.../".

I would really like for the URL to be with /admin. Here's my updated code:

**app/code/local/Tbe/Report/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

...

<!-- NOTHING HAS CHANGED HERE -->
<!-- I HAVE GOTTEN RID OF THE <adminhtml> NODE -->


<frontend>

    <routers>
        <report>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Tbe_Report</module>
                <frontName>report</frontName>
            </args>
        </report>
    </routers>

    <layout>
        <updates>
            <report>
                <file>report.xml</file>
            </report>
        </updates>
    </layout>  

</frontend>


<admin>

    <routers>
        <tbe_report>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Tbe_Report</module>
                <frontName>reported_products</frontName>
                <modules>
                    <Tbe_Report after="Mage_Adminhtml">Tbe_Report_Reported</Tbe_Report>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </tbe_report>
    </routers>

</admin>

</config>
```

**app/code/local/Tbe/Report/etc/adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<menu>
    <catalog translate="title" module="report">
        <title>Catalog</title>
        <sort_order>30</sort_order>
        <children>
            <report>
                <title>Reported Products</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/reported_products/reported/index</action>
            </report>
        </children>
    </catalog>
</menu>

...

</config>
```

**app/code/local/Tbe/Report/controllers/ReportedController.php**

```
class Tbe_Report_ReportedController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your controller is in /Tbe/Report/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php and not /Tbe/Report/controllers/IndexController.php therefore you need to use `<Tbe_Report after="Mage_Adminhtml">Tbe_Report_Adminhtml<...`

Try

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Tbe_Report after="Mage_Adminhtml">Tbe_Report_Adminhtml</Tbe_Report>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
```

Assuming the following folder structure.

```
app/code/local/Tbe/Report/controllers/Adminhtml/ReportedController.php
```

Menu

```
<action>adminhtml/reported/index/</action>
```

Comment: I have now moved the file Adminhtml/IndexController.php to ReportedController.php to stop confusion. Would I need to change it to Tbe_Report_Reported ?

Comment: If it is in the root controllers folder then it should just be Tbe_Report

Comment: Also the action in should start with adminhtml since you are using Mage_Adminhtml. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16510952/1191288

Comment: I'm not having much luck with that link. He hasn't explained it awfully well. Does it matter that my URL doesn't contain /admin?

Comment: There are two ways you can create admin module in magento and you seem to be mixing them. The only changes you should done was the one I listed above and it should have work.

Comment: Can you undo all the changes except for the one I listed above and let me know what happen

Comment: Certainly, I'm not able to do it right now, however. I'll let you know how I get on tomorrow. Thank you :) Should I redo my changes as per my initial post or my update?

Answer (score 0):

Make your menu link look like this:

```
<action>reported_products/adminhtml/index</action>
```

or better yet, declare your admin router as R.S described [in an other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31408896/2047249) and in this case you need to move your controller from `Tbe/Report/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php` to `Tbe/Report/controllers/Adminhtml/Reported/IndexController.php` (change the class name accordingly also) and you can have your menu link like this:

```
<action>adminhtml/reported/index</action>
```

Comment: Neither of your suggestions have worked. Without the adminhtml at the start of the action, the url does not contain an admin URL. Note: I have changed the location and name of controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php to controllers/ReportedController.php